# Spring Boot ignores an environment variable

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to run this `docker-compose` file (I trimmed it a bit)

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
    depends_on:
      eureka:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      EUREKA_URL: http://eureka:8761/eureka

  eureka:
    image: nadchel/eureka-server:1.0
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://eureka:8761"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

The relevant part about the app is it has a Eureka client dependency

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>token-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>token-service</name>
    <description>token-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!-- ... -->

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

The problem is the app's failure to connect to the Eureka container

```
token-service-app-1     | 2024-02-21T23:41:51.863Z  WARN 1 --- [token-service] [nfoReplicator-0]
c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: 
I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/TOKEN-SERVICE": 
Connect to http://localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
```

As you see, I passed an environment variable that used the service's name as the host. The variable *is* used in the app's property file

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: token-service

eureka:
  client:
    availability-zones:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

So why does it still try to connect by `localhost`?

**UPD:** Let me address some of the points:

1. Some suggested the dictionary format of properties is wrong, but actually it's explicitly allowed in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#environment). Here's an example they gave:

```yaml
environment:
  RACK_ENV: development
  SHOW: 'true'
  SESSION_SECRET:
```

2. I *checked*, the property is *present* in the container

```
docker exec token-service-app-1 /bin/sh -c "env"                                                                              
POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres                                                                                                                                                  
HOSTNAME=2e671f5bd313                                                                                                                                                       
SHLVL=1                                                                                                                                                                     
HOME=/root                                                                                                                                                                  
EUREKA_URL=http://eureka:8761/eureka                                                                                                                                        
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres                                                                                                                                                  
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/bin                                                                              
LANG=C.UTF-8                                                                                                                                                                
POSTGRES_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres                                                                                                                             
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm                                                                                                                                          
PWD=/app
```

3. Also, I tried checking whether it has to do with different Spring Boot versions

```xml
<!-- Eureka's pom: Boot's and Cloud's versions are a bit older -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EurekaServer</name>
    <description>EurekaServer</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
```

But then I ran a different compose file *which had exactly the same mismatch*, and it worked fine

Comment: A YAML mapping should be accepted too; see for example the [Compose File v3 definition of `environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment).

Comment: @DavidMaze what can I try?

Comment: I think the typo is a missing dash in front of the environmental variable name in the docker file. Bit premature to close a post when that has not been confirmed yet :/

Comment: I don't believe `eureka.client.availability-zones.defaultZone` is the right setting it should be  `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` from what I see in the docs?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I ran it fine with no Docker, with exactly that `availability-zones` property: `2024-02-22T20:59:01.858+03:00  INFO 13880 --- [token-service] [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_TOKEN-SERVICE/host.docker.internal:token-service:8100: registering service...
2024-02-22T20:59:01.914+03:00  INFO 13880 --- [token-service] [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_TOKEN-SERVICE/host.docker.internal:token-service:8100 - registration status: 204`

Comment: When you ran it without docker where was your Eureka server present? On localhost right? That's the default which it is trying to access with docker as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've configured your apps properties for the Eureka client incorrectly. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/reference/html/#registering-with-eureka) it should be configured like so:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

To be clear instead of `availability-zones` it should be `serviceUrl`.

Comment: You were right. Thank you again! (my previous comment disappeared for some reason)